# Como dar formato entre comillas

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Buen dia, tengo una respuesta que recibo de json `json[0].id_sucursal` que me llega asi 1, 2, 4, como hago para que cada numero llegue en fomato entero y no string `[1, 2, 4]` todo estto para que el multiselect lo muestre como preseleccion al editar datos de un usuario

---

Esta es la linea no acepta los string y alli solo me selecciona un solo elemento del menu multiselect, el primero

```
$('#sucNewUser').multiselect('select', [parseInt(json[0].id_sucursal)])
```

Comment: ¿Por que necesitas que sean cadenas? ¿Vos generas el arreglo `[1,2,4]` con PHP? Por favor, presiona [edit] y agrega el código relacionado a tu pregunta.

Comment: @Marcos asi es yo leeo desde la base de datos el valor que viene asi [1,2,4]

Comment: Exprese mal la pregunta al recibirlos en javascript los quiero hacer enteros a cada numero

Comment: ¿Intentaste con `json[0].id_sucursal[0]`?

Comment: Te llega una string de números separados por coma y quieres convertirlo a un arreglo de enteros?

Comment: @Fedex7501 correcto eso mismo cual seria el procedimiento ando aun perdido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `split` para separar  y `map` para convertir a entero:

```
$('#sucNewUser').multiselect('select',json[0].id_sucursal.split(',').map(x => parseInt(x)))
```

Comment: i love you, funciono perfecto